# Do you say "aneinu" if you don't eat anything all day but drink lots of water?

Tags: shemoneh-esrei

Do you say "aneinu" if you don't eat anything all day but drink lots of water?

Comment: Are you asking about a fast day or a regular day? Please edit your post to specify

Comment: When you drink water on a fast day, you haven't fasted.

Comment: @ezra This is the answer. You should post as an answer.

Answer (score 7):

In an [article](http://www.yeshiva.co/midrash/shiur.asp?id=2399) about fast days, [Rabbi Eliezer Melamed](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eliezer_Melamed) writes the following:

> One who ate or drank during the fast: if it was less than "Kezayit"
>   (an olive’s bulk) of food, or "Kimlo Logmav" (a cheekful) of liquid
>   that was consumed, "Aneinu" may be recited, for, technically, this is
>   not seen as a break in the fast. If more than this amount was eaten,
>   because the fast was broken, one may not recite "Aneinu."

Comment: This answer assumes that O.P. means drinking water on a public fast day. Since he hasn't clarified this, I don't know if you've answered the question. I've voted to close the question because it is unclear.

Comment: @richardts You shouldn't hold by _any_ rabbi quoted on this site. Questions concerning genuine p'sak halacha should be directed towards your local Orthodox rabbi.

Comment: ביאור הלכה תקסה א כתב הח"א יחיד שאינו מתענה ומתפלל עם הצבור יאמר בש"ת ענינו ויאמר ביום ת"צ זה [א"ז בשם הב"ח] עכ"ל ובמאמר מרדכי השיג ע"ז ע"ש ודבריו נכונים דיחיד שאינו מתענה אין לומר עננו בשום פנים: